# How to remove text without clicking button

Tags: java, netbeans-8

```
 private void jngtAlSiurblioIjungimasMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                     

    if (jngtAlSiurblioIjungimas.isSelected()) {
        AlSiurbIjungDisplay.setText("At first i would like to print this");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (Exception r) {// after 3000 mls i would like that all text was be deleted automaticly
        }
     AlSiurbIjungDisplay.setText("");
        }
```

//I am using Netbeans 8.1.My task is when i start,at first that was printing first:

```
AlSiurbIjungDisplay.setText("At first i would like to print this");
```

,and after `300 ml` what was printing at panel was be remove,or deleted,my problem is when i starting not printing

```
AlSiurbIjungDisplay.setText("At first i would like to print this");
```

Why,please help me

Answer (score 0):

So here is my answear How to remove text without clicking button:NEED TI USE method:
ActionListener listene = (ActionEvent eventt) -> {
            PgrindinisDisplay.setText("");

if (jngtVandensTiekimoSklende.isSelected()) {
            PgrindinisDisplay.setText(" Vandens tiekimo sklende atidaroma ");

```
    }
    ActionListener listener = (ActionEvent event) -> {// gaunasi raip: po kiekvieno 
        PgrindinisDisplay.setText("Vandens tiekimo sklende atidaryta");
    };// po kiekvieno action listenener is settex darome }; 
    ActionListener listene = (ActionEvent eventt) -> {
        PgrindinisDisplay.setText("");
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer(4000, listener);//kiekvienam Actionlistener sukuriame taimeri
    Timer tm = new Timer(4000, listene);

    tm.start();// o cia svarbu irgi eiliskumas 
    timer.setRepeats(false);// sito gali ir nebuti vistiek veikia
    timer.start();
```